# Which is better? Using 2 arrays or array of pair?

Tags: c++, arrays, caching

I have few objects and each object has 2 attributes alpha and beta. 
I have large number of operations where I am given the object and I need to get the values of alpha and beta of the corresponding object. There are 2 ways to do it -

1) Use 2 arrays - One for alpha and one for beta

```
for(each query){
    cin>>index;
    int val1 = alpha[index];
    int val2 = beta[index];
    //Do something with val1 and val2
}
```

2) Use array of pair

```
for(each query){
    cin>>index;
    pair<int,int> requiredPair = pairArray[index];
    int val1 = requiredPair.first;
    int val2 = requiredPair.second;
    //Do something with val1 and val2
}
```

Which of the above methods is more efficient? I am thinking that because of caching, method 2 would be more efficient. Is it true? Also, what if there are multiple attributes for each object. Is it better using multiple arrays or just one array of struct?

Comment: Measure, measure, measure... we can't possibly predict caching behaviour etc. with just this code.

Comment: use method 2. No need to multiply entities.

Comment: If you're really doing input and `cin>>index` is not just an example, then it does not matter.

Comment: I vote for an array of `pair`s. That keeps related data together.

Comment: For code maintainability and cache locality, the answer is almost always method 2, but you still need to measure, unless you are using `cin` in which case this optimization is going to be unnoticable.

Comment: Considering your last statement about multiple attributes in particular as a more general form of your problem, I think it's wise to go with an array of objects rather than  multiple arrays of smaller objects - less to do/worry about/get wrong, less worrying about where everything is, and keeping the arrays synchronized, etc. So many advantages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CPU caching strategy relies on data being spatially and temporally proximate. In other words accesses that are close in time are assumed to be close in memory address.

So if you are accessing both fields in a record together then a single array will probably make more sense. If you are accessing all the records in one field and then all the records in another then 2 arrays may make more sense.

As an aside, I generally avoid `std::pair` and prefer a `struct` since `first` and `second` have less meaning that `name` and `date` in a `struct`.